# How do I auto generate products via attribute?

Tags: commerce

I have a shoe store, as you know, Drupal Commerce allow us to control each Attribute of Shoe like Color and Size.

This is my problem :

I have 2000 shoe styles, each style has sizes from 5-12 (6US to 12US)
It mean that everytime I add new style, I have to create 8 products for 8 sizes. Im using Clone Product Module, it's working very well, but how can I save my time :

It mean that when I create New Shoe Style (Node Products Display)
--> node/add/shoe-style
--> the system will auto generate 8 products (Size) for me, it depend on how many value in my attribute field (Size attribute has 8 value and system will create 8 new product), and now what we need to do is update something to each product.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Drupal 7, you've got a couple of options:

1. [Commerce Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_migrate) will let you create products as part of a migration. It's a bit more time consuming but it's repeatable and is very powerful.
2. You can use [Commerce Bulk Product Creation](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_bpc) to create products based off of fields in the UI. This gives the ability to create those products once and isn't repeatable.

Comment: Commerce Bulk Product Creation is awesome, you save my day, thank you so much @nvahalik